# Recomment free cells on matrix . using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, matrix

I have two table's like

1. **container**

   it contains

   - **refid** as primarykey
   - **rows** // number of rows in a matrix
   - **columns** // number of columns in a matrix
2. **data_on_matrix**

   it contains

   - **refid** as primarykey
   - **cell_id**  // the cell of the data placed on matrix
   - **text_data**  // data on matrix
   - **container_id**  // data on matrix

[image here](http://s24.postimg.org/5sdehjglh/9781593370312_0023_001.jpg)

I am just make this UI by container **column** X **rows**. If someone click on any cell that cell was filled by data by inserting one row on `data_on_matrix` **table**.

**My Problem is**

How to recomment free cells on the container for users. How to achive by this 
whether SQL or Any UI tricks available for that?

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: Why do you not store a `rownr` and `colnr` on your matrix? Would make it much easier to find the right row. Then you only need a table 'numbers' with numbers 1..100 and you can join numbers as cols, numbers as rows left join data_on_matrix where cols.nr ... and cols.nr < (numcols)

Comment: This should be solved in php not SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(repeating from comment)

If you look for cells in a matrix which are not there, you need a "numbers" table since SQL can't create something out of nothing.

```
create table numbers (nr int(11) not null primary key auto_increment);
insert into numbers values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
```

(and so on until you maximal ever possible or thinkable dimension).

Then you need the row number and column number of your data_on_matrix entry:

```
alter table data_on_matrix add column row_id int(11) not null, add column col_id int(11) not null;
```

If you want to read the cells of a matrix which are already there, you just read

```
select row_id, col_id, text_data from data_on_matrix where refid = {$refid};
```

If you look for free cells, just select

```
select r.nr as row_id, c.nr as col_id
from numbers r, numbers c
left join data_on_matrix d on d.col_id = c.id and d.row_id = r.id and d.refid = {$refId}
where d.ref_id is null and r.id <= {$rows} and c.id <= {$columns}
```

with refid, rows and columns coming out of table `container`. It would also be easy to join container directly, but probably you already have a list of containers with their properties in php.